# Slashes automatically added to text boxes php

Tags: php, textbox, slash

I have been racking my brain to understand why there are slashes ("/") in every one of by textboxes on my page when I run this php script. Everything on the page works fine. I have tried everything but they're just there. Here my whole code below. Thanks for any help!

```
function validateInput($data, $fieldName){
    global $error;
    if (empty($data)){
        echo "\"$fieldName\" is a required field.<br />\n";
        ++$error;
        $retval = "";
    } else if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]/', $data) == 0){
        echo "\"$fieldName\" can only contain letters.<br />\n";
        ++$error;
        $retval = "";
    } else {
        $retval = trim($stripslashes($data));
    }
    return ($retval);
}

function validateAddress($data, $fieldName){
    global $error;
    if (empty($data)){
        echo "\"$fieldName\" is a required field.<br />\n";
        ++$error;
        $retval = "";
    } else if (!preg_match('/[^0-9A-Za-z]/', $data)){
        echo "\"$fieldName\" can only contain letters or numbers.<br />\n";
        ++$error;
        $retval = "";
    } else {
        $retval = trim(stripslashes($data));
    }
    return ($retval);
}

function validateNumber($data, $fieldName){
    global $error;
    if (empty($data)){
        echo "\"$fieldName\" is a required field.<br />\n";
        ++$error;
        $retval = "";
    } else if (!is_numeric($data)){
        echo "\"$fieldName\" must contain only numbers.<br />";
        ++$error;
        $retval = "";
    } else if (strlen($data) != 10){
        echo "\"$fieldName\" must be 10 numbers long.<br />";
        ++$error;
        $retval = "";
    } else {
        $retval = trim(stripslashes($data));
    }
    return ($retval);
}

function validateEmail($data, $fieldName){
    global $error;
    if (empty($data)){
        echo "\"$fieldName\" is a required field.<br />\n";
        ++$error;
        $retval = "";
    } else {
        $retval = trim(stripslashes($input));
        $pattern = "/^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@" .
            "[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*" .
            "(\.[a-z]{2,})$/i";
        if (preg_match($pattern, $retval) == 0){
            echo "\"$fieldName\" is not a valid email address.<br />\n";
            ++$error;
        }
    }
    return($retval);
}

function displayForm($name, $email, $address, $phone){
    include("header.html");
    ?>
    <div class="center">
    <form name="contact_us" action="contact_us.php" method="post">
    <p>Your Name: <input type="text" name="name" value=<?php echo $name; ?> /></p>
    <p>Your Email: <input type="text" name="email" value=<?php echo $email; ?> /></p>
    <p>Your Address: <input type="text" name="address" value=<?php echo $address; ?> /></p>
    <p>Your Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone" value=<?php echo $phone;?> /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send" />&nbsp;
    <input type="reset" value="Clear"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    include("footer.html");
}

$showForm = TRUE;
$error = 0;
$name = "";
$email = "";
$address = "";
$phone = "";

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $name = validateInput($_POST['name'], "Name");
    $email = validateEmail($_POST['email'], "Email");
    $address = validateAddress($_POST['address'], "Address");
    $phone = validateNumber($_POST['phone'], "Phone");

    if ($error == 0)
        $showForm = FALSE;
    else 
        $showForm = TRUE;
}

if ($showForm == TRUE){
    if ($error > 0)
        echo "<p>Please re-enter the form information below.<br/>\n";
    displayForm($name, $email, $address, $phone);
} else {
    echo "Your contact information has been recorded. Thank you!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Not sure if this affects the code at all, but you should quote your `value` attributes in case your variables contain spaces: e.g. `<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />`

Comment: @mc10 I bet that is the issue. `... value=<?php echo $name; ?> />` when value is blank is saying `... value= />` which you are just saying the value is `/`.

Comment: Like Jon said, it looks like you aren't ever outputting quotes for your `value="whatever"` fields.  Also, the `$` before the `stripSlashes` in `validateInput` is probably a typo.

Comment: So you should have `<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />` though I'm not convinced that is the only problem here.

Comment: Adding the quotation marks fixed it! Can't believe it was such a simple error. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote your `value` attributes in these lines:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value=<?php echo $name; ?> />
```

If `$name` is empty, which is true by default, your code reduces to

```
<input type="text" name="name" value=/ >
```

So your input boxes are filled with a `/` by default. To fix this error (and avoid other possible errors), quote your `$name`:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>" />
```

Notice that I also called [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to prevent XSS.

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs addslashes() on all GET, POST, and COOKIE data by default.